# Extracting items from a Map using a step

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin you can extract list items using a step like this:

```
val numbers = listOf("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six")    
println(numbers.slice(0..4 step 2))
```

Is there a similar way to do this for a map? So instead of listOf, I'm using mapOf.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to think about whether it makes sense to use slice on a Map. The Map interface does not guarantee an order, so it does not have the concept of indices that you can select from, which is what `slice` does.

If your Map is backed by a specific implementation that guarantees an iteration order, such as LinkedHashMap, then it can make sense to convert the Map's entries into a List so you can slice them, and then you can convert the result back to a Map.

```
val result = someLinkedHashMap
  .entries
  .toList()
  .slice(someRange)
  .associate { it.key to it.value } // change the filtered entries list into a new map
```

The `associate` function's documentation guarantees a Map implementation that has consistent execution order.

Answer (score 0):

[`slice()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/slice.html) is an extension function for Arrays and Lists.

To convert a Map to a List, first [get the entries Set](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/entries.html), and then [convert the Set into a List](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-list.html).

[Run in Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/upbZd0FKq)

```kotlin
fun main() {
  val numbers = mapOf(
    "one" to 1, 
    "two" to 2, 
    "three" to 3, 
    "four" to 4, 
    "five" to 5, 
    "six" to 6,
  )

  // get the Map entries, and convert them to a List - then slice
  val sliced = numbers.entries.toList().slice(0..4 step 2)

  println(sliced)
}
```

Output:

```
[one=1, three=3, five=5]
```